# Python Gtk.MessageDialog Hides Parent Window

Tags: python, gtk3

I am working on a Gtk3 app written in Python. The main window for my app is set up as follows:

```
#!/bin/python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk as Gtk

## OTHER IMPORTS

class MainGui(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="APP TITLE")

        # Defaults
        self.set_default_size(600, 500)

        ## OTHER CODE            

        # Setup the Window
        self.connect("destroy", self.on_close)
        self.show_all()

    ## OTHER CODE    

    def on_close(self, widget):
        if self.editor.get_document().get_has_changes():
            save_dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(self, 0,
                Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
                Gtk.ButtonsType.YES_NO,
                "Save changes?")
            response = save_dialog.run()

            ## REST OF DIALOG HANDELING
```

The problem I'm having is related to the save dialog. The app displays the dialog just fine, but it hides my main window, which is not the desired effect. I've tried searching around for a solution, but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this I realized that the reason things weren't working is because of a bone-headed mistake. I was hooking up my on_close method using this:

```
self.connect("destroy", self.on_close)
```

It turns out I should be doing it this way:

```
self.connect("delete-event", self.on_close)
```

Now things work great.